# Error : 502 bad gateway in SAP Webide Multi-cloud version

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform, sap-web-ide

I'm getting an error as 502 bad gateway in SAP Webide while making data connection using template in webide. I'm trying to load data from On-Premise SAP ABAP system after checking cloud connector and Destination availability, but still getting the same error. Please help me with the solution.

[image: SAP Web IDE Screenshot of connecting remote server "502 Bad Gateway"]

Comment: Has it worked before? Does it work with other apps and services using the same gateway? Maybe the following docu helps: [Requirements for Connecting to ABAP Systems](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide/frameset.htm?5a55141b8dff41c8b87adb4222aba3b8.html) or [Connecting Remote Systems](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide/frameset.htm?5c3debce758a470e8342161457fd6f70.html) or [Connecting Remote Systems in SAP Web IDE Personal Edition](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide/frameset.htm?2cf47f37e34c428c97a51057733c0394.html)

Comment: @SAPFioriCrew No, It doesn't work with other apps and services from same gateway. I am using Webide on MAC OS and windows (running on VM ware) in both the cases i'm facing same problem(i.e: 502 Bad Gateway or sometimes 403 forbidden). It is working fine With SAP Web IDE personal edition i'm able to to load data from On-Premise SAP ABAP system but not able to load data from On-Premise system to cloud version of Webide . We tried on colleague's windows system(Without VM ware) with same settings as i had in my system it does work fine.

Comment: The error 403 refers to your user being forbidden the requested operation.
If you compare both users of yourself and your colleague, do you find any differences?
Are these users configured the same way in the network and on the gateway server?

Comment: Yes both the users sharing the same network and we did not find any differences in configuration, only the Operating System is different. I am using Mac OSx Ei Capitan (and Windows 10 on VM ware) and colleague's  system is just Windows 10. 
Please find the attachments in the below links.
http://i.imgur.com/L7tbMWC.png
http://imgur.com/a/YWGP3

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem after checking the configuration in cloud connector i.e., i configured the /sap/opu/odata path but excluded any sub-paths instead i should include all sub-paths as shown in below image.

[image]

[image]